# Emacs modes/functions and xmonad

Tags: emacs, workspace, xmonad

So I'm wondering if it's possible to take XMonad's ability to shift certain applications to specific workspaces a step further and apply it to specific modes/functions of Emacs?

For example I have mod+shift+u bound to `spawn "emacs -f mu4e"` which runs drops me into mu4e, the mail mode/function that i'm using to read mail. I'd like to bind that to a specific workspace instead of just opening in whatever workspace i'm in at present.

The problem (or not really a problem) is that I use Emacs extensively (mail, irc, etc.) and i'd like to have the specific modes/functions associated with workspaces and not have to move them there manually. I've looked at many XMonad.hs configurations and it seems that a huge majority use apps like pidgin, xchat, etc. and so it's trivial to setup the workspace association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could specify a specific window title for your Emacs frame and use it to setup the workspace association (instead of the window class, which I assume you'd use for pidgin or xchat)

`emacs --title "mu4e" -f mu4e`

I don't know xmonad, but if it is not able to provide workspace associations based on windows titles, you could use a tool like wmctrl instead. For example (assuming you want to move to the desktop number 4):

`wmctrl -r mu4e -t 4`

Comment: That did it, I set a title and added the following to my manageHook "title =? mu4e" --> viewShift <workspace_here>".